# HaxeFlixel how to fire touch event to fire when touching sprite

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I have a sprite on the screen that I want to fire a event when touched.  I managed it with the mouse event but can't get it work with touch input.

```haxe
//This works for mouse. eg.
import flixel.input.mouse.FlxMouseEventManager;
...
add(sprite);
FlxMouseEventManager.add(sprite, onMouseDown, onMouseUp, onMouseOver, onMouseOut);

// Need to work out how to fire event for touch.
I would like the touch equivalent for a sprite. 
FlxTouch????  (needs to be fixed)
```

Comment: Woow, I am surprised that no one seem to know the anwer to this seemingly simple question, but I think I know why now.  I think I have the answer I was looking for.

Comment: ANSWER:  The onMouseOver works on the mobile devices.  I have tested this on Android & IOS and it Works!!  I hope this helps someone else out there with the same problem.  Happy coding Lee

Comment: If there is a better way of doing this then please let me know.  thanks

Comment: Hey Lee, I think the haxeflixel community is not that active in StackOverflow to get an answer in just one day. Btw you might get better response posting in their forum http://forum.haxeflixel.com/